# Unity Android Touch Handle

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, touches

i have this code in my script

its working fine in my first scene. it means i,ll click on an 
Special object collider and i can do something . but in another scene it works only when my player is in the collider . and when player is in . touching any point giving me the collider  touch result. any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**ALWAYS:** Make a back-up copy of your work before deleting assets or reworking how your game flow works (ie: copying and adding new scenes).

**ONE:**  It is possible that you created the two scenes with different versions of your prefab objects.  If you bring a prefab into a scene and then alter that scene's object, the stored prefab will not automatically inherit the changes you made.

If you want to update your prefab, delete the old version and drag the new one into the prefab folder.

**TWO:** Your colliders are configured differently between the scenes.

**To DEBUG:** Make a third scene by copying the scene that works properly and see if you can switch to this new scene without seeing the bug.  If that is successful than you know the bug is on some object/collider in the broken scene.

Comment: ok !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Let me know if you find out anything from debugging.

Comment: noting yet!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: i,ll find the problem . my code is only for orthographic camera.

Comment: thanks any way !!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Not sure if your problem is with your touch code.  Do you have the collider set to OnTriggerEnter?  That could explain the weird behavior.

Comment: its solved . thanks . i have another question . how can i set a camera to render and culling mask a special game object contain some sprite?? the camera is orphographic. or force camera to render special depth??

Comment: its so simple so i mention it here

Comment: Hmm, why don't you make this into a new question and then post the link to it here!

Comment: ok but stackoverflow errors whhhhooooffff

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34457916/camera-rendering-culling-mask-and-depth