# Camera rendering culling mask and depth

Tags: unity-game-engine, camera

In the 2D game I have 2 orthographic cameras and two game objects, one behind another.
Near game objects have transparent sprites so we can see the back game object.
The near game object's depth is 0 and the other one's is -1.  I want my first camera to render the near scene and another camera to render the back game object. The first camera follows the character so I want the second camera to follow him slowly and to show nice graphics.

Comment: i try to use perspective cameras but my object touch handler wont work that way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The game object that you only want visible to one camera should be put in it's own layer.  Then you can use its camera's culling mask to only see that layer (Or lets say that layer and the background layer).

Then for the camera that should never see the object, uncheck the object's layer.
Here is a video on the subject [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iYaOkbC58W4) from Pluralsite on Youtube.

Comment: that was so helpful so . how can i activate both camera at the same time??

Comment: Are you looking to have one camera be the main scene view, and another to be a 'map' or 'radar' ?

Comment: nope .its a 2d game . my character only can walk to left and right.  i want my back object(jungle) move slower with character moves to show that jungle is far. like "Limbo" game

Comment: Got it.  Put this in a new question!

Comment: so both cameras should be activated at same time.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34458175/activate-two-cameras-at-the-same-time