# Activate Two Cameras At The Same Time

Tags: unity-game-engine, camera

How do I activate 2 cameras at the same time? The first camera follows the character and the second camera follows the character more slowly. After a while we can't see the character with the second camera but the point is each camera renders a special game object.  The second camera renders the back game object. So two cameras with each other make better scene moving. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are looking to implement a scene background parallax where the background appears to be moving across the scene slower than the forground.

Take a look at this video about separating your scene's layers.  There is a quick fix solution in the first few minutes of the video, and a longer re-work that is a good idea to think about.

[Parallax Scrolling](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=30OuWY1UfcQ)

Comment: I'm glad it worked!  That is a great way to render a background and cut down on how much background you actually need, because far away landscapes can move slower, so you don't need that much of it. :)